# Recover Partition Table After Remove Partition (parted)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, partition-recovery

I deleted a partition using `(parted) rm 3`, so I could extend my `ext4` partition. Here was my partition table before I removed it:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      32.3kB  99.1GB  99.1GB  primary   ntfs            boot
3      208GB   240GB   32.2GB  extended                  lba
5      208GB   238GB   30.2GB  logical   ext4
6      238GB   240GB   2009MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
2      240GB   250GB   9977MB  primary   ntfs
```

After I ran `(parted) rm 3` it shows up like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      32.3kB  99.1GB  99.1GB  primary  ntfs         boot
2      240GB   250GB   9977MB  primary  ntfs
```

Since I only removed number 3, I don't understand where my `ext4` partition and my `linux-swap(v1)` partition went. I am attempting to restore my partition table using `sudo gpart /dev/sda`, however I read online that it doesn't support `ext4` partitions.

Anyone have any suggestions? I would like my `ext4` and `linux-swap(v1)` partitions back, and ideally to extend the `ext4` partition to use the empty space before it.

---

EDIT:

`gpart` failed to find my correct partition. I am now trying to use `testdisk` which will hopefully correctly identify my partition table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to recover my system. Just in case anyone else has the same problem, I'll outline what I did.

First I ran `testdisk`, which (mostly) recovered my partition table. Now it shows:

```
1      32.3kB  99.1GB  99.1GB  primary   ntfs            boot
2      208GB   238GB   30.2GB  primary   ext4
3      238GB   240GB   2012MB  extended                  lba
5      238GB   240GB   2009MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
4      240GB   250GB   9977MB  primary   ntfs
```

Than, I rebooted as `testdisk` asked me to do. However, upon trying to boot GRUB failed and went into rescue mode. I then booted from a Ubuntu Live CD, ran `boot-repair` which fixed GRUB and restarted a final time.

It is now running and I cannot see any problems with it, although I still have not figured out how to extend my partition.

Comment: Okay, now, if you came to the new partition structure, as can be viewed from this answer, you can extend your `ext4`, Now it is easier, because it became a `primary` partition, not `logical` as it was before. It is assuming that you have enough gree space at `1` partition and you are ready to sacrifice it to another one. So just run [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) and resize `1` ntfs, make it less, make your `2` ext4 partition bigger by pulling its left border to the left side, where the `1` ntfs partition ends. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The total data storage space of a PC HDD can be divided into at most four primary partitions, or alternatively three primary partitions and an extended partition. These partitions are described by 16-byte entries that constitute the Partition Table, located in the master boot record.

A primary partition contains one file system.

An HDD may contain only one extended partition; the extended partition can be subdivided into multiple logical partitions.

You deleted :

`3      208GB   240GB   32.2GB  extended`

which contained:

`5      208GB   238GB   30.2GB  logical   ext4
6      238GB   240GB   2009MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)`

I don't believe that you would be able to extend this `ext 4` partition to more than 2Gb (the size of `swap` if you had deleted it)

As soon as you restore your data from `ext4` you will need to delete `3` extended partition again, and if you want to make the new partition bigger, you will need to resize `1` or `2`(make one of them or both less). The extra space you can take is only, in your case, from `1` or `2` partitions (both are ntfs in your case). iif you are able to run Windows still, it would be probably easier for you to involve windows software to operate., so I would advise [Partition Wizard Mini Tool](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)

As for restoring your partition,  if it is from Windows again, try for example [Partition Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/ad/partition-recovery.htm) , it promises:

> Recover data from deleted partitions (accidentally deleted or using
>   programs)
>
> Restore files from lost partition caused by repartitioning, boot
>   manager, hard drive crash, virus attack, system installation, etc.
>
> Gat data back from quick or full formatted partition
>
> Recover files from corrupted partition with "Disk is not formatted"
>   error
>
> Recover data from inaccessible partition, hard drive, USB drive,
>   floppy disk, etc.
>
> Recover data from FAT/NTFS/EXT2/EXT3 partition
>
> Restrive data from reformatted volumes or devices
>
> Recover data from RAW partition or when no files can be read from RAW
>   disk, RAW USB drive, RAW SD card, etc.
>
> Recover data after an MBR corruption
>
> Recover data from improper or other partition errors

UPDATE:
Okay, now, if you came to the new partition structure, as can be viewed from your answer below, you can extend your `ext4`. Now it is easier, because it became a `primary` partition, not `logical` as it was before. It is assuming that you have enough free space at `1` partition and you are ready to sacrifice it to another one. So just run [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) 
if you don't have it then install it `sudo apt-get install gparted` or from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) 
[image]

and resize `1` ntfs, make it less, make your `2` ext4 partition bigger by pulling its left border to the left side, where the `1` ntfs partition ends. Press `Apply` every time you want to write changes to the disk.

Comment: I realize what I did wrong now. I just shrunk partition 1 and, completely not thinking, assumed that when I shrunk it, it auto-created partition 3, which I was then going to delete and extend my ext4 partition (number 5) to the free space. Looking at the partition table I posted below, I am going to extend partition 2 (ext4) to the free space before it.